# Axios in a firebase function returning pending promise even inside two async/await blocks

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, asynchronous, async-await

I have an async/await problems (I know, I know) that makes no sense to me. I'm declaring both functions (child and HOF) as async, and awaiting the returned results before trying to console log them. Surprise surprise, I get pending. The function hangs for 60s and times out (so it seems even my `runWith` timeout method isn't working. Also tried logging a simple "here" right before declaring `const fetchData`, but also that didn't log. And yet console logging after actually calling the fn does...

```
exports.getBitcoinPrice = functions
    .region("europe-west1")
    .runWith({ timeoutSeconds: 5 })
    .https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
      const fetchData = async () => {
        return await axios
          .get("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json", {
            timeout: 2000,
          })
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .catch((error) => console.log(error));
      };
      const data = await fetchData();
      console.log(await data);
      return null;
    });
```

I wanted to use `fetch` but apparently `node-fetch` doesn't work well with firebase.

I will try to provide a list of the many SO posts and articles I've read about async/await. I've done the research and tried all of their implementations, but still can't resolve it.

Stack overflow formatting is not working, so:

[Axios returning pending promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63679339/axios-returning-pending-promise)
[async/await return Promise { <pending> }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52120218/async-await-return-promise-pending)
[Why is my asynchronous function returning Promise { <pending> } instead of a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884522/why-is-my-asynchronous-function-returning-promise-pending-instead-of-a-val)
[Async/await return Promise<pending>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52577549/async-await-return-promisepending)
https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson/issues/278
https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/h90s0u/call_external_api_from_cloud_function/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using too many `await` in your code. 
If you want to use `await` on the `fetchData` function you should return a `Promise` and handle it outside.

Try to change your code like this:

```
exports.getBitcoinPrice = functions
    .region("europe-west1")
    .runWith({ timeoutSeconds: 5 })
    .https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
      const fetchData = () => {
        return axios
          .get("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json", {
            timeout: 2000,
          })
      };

      try {
        const { data } = await fetchData();
        console.log(data);
      } catch (err) {
          console.log(err)
      }
      return null;
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much @luca . This is the correct answer, with two sidenotes: 1. In axios, we don't use `data.json()` (I've jsut learned). in the `fetchData` fn, I had to append a `.then(response => response.data)`. 2. Typo in the catch block; change to `catch (error)`.

Comment: @crevulus Fixed both in the answer, thank you for pointing those out!